# Operator precedence issue in Perl and PHP

Tags: php, perl, operator-precedence

PHP:

```
$a = 2;
$b = 3;
if($b=1 && $a=5)
{
   $a++;
   $b++;
}
echo $a.'-'.$b;


$a = 2;
$b = 3;
if($a=5 and $b=1)
{
   $a++;
   $b++;
}
echo $a.'-'.$b;
```

Output `6-16-2`.I don't understand the `1` here.

Perl :

```
$a = 2;
$b = 3;
if($b=1 && $a=5)
{
     $a++;                                                                            
     $b++;
}
print $a.'-'.$b;


$a = 2;
$b = 3;
if($a=5 and $b=1)
{
    $a++;
    $b++;
}
print $a.'-'.$b;
```

Output `6-66-2`, I don't understand the second `6` here.

Anyone knows the reason?

Actually I know `&&` has higher precedence than `and`,but I still has the doubt when knowing this before hand.

**UPDATE**

Now I understand the PHP one,what about the Perl one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regarding Perl:

Unlike PHP (but like Python, JavaScript, etc.) the boolean operators don't return a boolean value but the value that <del>made the expression true (or the last value)</del> determines the final result of the expression<sup>†</sup> ([source](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/prog3/ch01_05.htm)).

```
$b=1 && $a=5
```

is evaluated as

```
$b = (1 && $a=5) // same as in PHP
```

which is the same as  `$b = (1 && 5)` (assignment "returns" the assigned value) and assigns `5` to `$b`.

---

The bottom line is: The operator precedence is the same in Perl and PHP (at least in this case), but they differ in what value is returned by the boolean operators.

FWIW, PHP's operator precedence can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

---

What's more interesting (at least this was new to me) is that PHP does not perform type conversion for the increment/decrement operators.

So if `$b` is `true`, then `$b++` leaves the value as `true`, while e.g. `$b += 1` assigns `2` to `$b`.

---

†: What I mean with this is that it returns the first (leftmost) value which

- evaluates to `false` in case of `&&`
- evaluates to `true` in case of `||`

or the last value of the expression.

Comment: In Python it returns first false-converted to false or last overwise. I think Perl do same way

Comment: @JeRog - a `&&` expression will stop evaluating when a false value is encountered, so in `1&&0&&5`, `0` is the last value. Likewise, `1&&undef&&5` will evaluate to `undef`.

Comment: @Je Rog `&&` returns its left argument if its left argument is false; otehrwise it returns its right argument. `||` returns its left argument if its left argument is true, otherwise it returns its right argument. So a chain of `&&` returns the leftmost false value (or the last value if all were true) and a chain of `||` returns the leftmost true value (or the last value if all were false).

Comment: @RiaD: Right. I think a better way to express this is: It returns that value that determines the final result of the expression. Updated.

Answer (score 5):

First example

```
$a = 2;
$b = 3;
if($b=1 && $a=5)  // means $b = (1 && $a=5)
{
   var_dump($b); //bool(true) because of &&
   $a++;
   $b++; //bool(true)++ ==true, ok
}
echo $a.'-'.$b;
```

hope you will not use those codes in production)

I'm noob in perl but i can suggest a&&b returns a or b (last of them if all of them converted to bool), not boolean, then $b = (1 && $a=5) returns $b=5 (is 5)

Comment: This is very insightful, but stops short of answering the OP's question. Why does php consider `$b` to be boolean? And what the heck is perl doing in the OP's example?

Comment: Makes you wonder if putting the assignment in a conditional hinted PHP that you want a boolean instead of a number, so it cast to the wrong type...

Comment: Now I found why it's boolean.(I consider itis because of operator priority )

Comment: @Asaph The question is about the differences between precedence in PHP and Perl. Why would there NOT be Perl in OP's example?

Comment: @Asaph, obviously PHP is interpreting it as `$b=(1 && $a=5)`.

Comment: It's probably `((bool)1 && (bool)($a = 5))` then. In perl, that would amount to `1 ? $a = 5 : 1` i.e. `5`. Depends on the type system then.

Comment: @Je Rog: Exactly. I was hoping to gently nudge RiaD to include that bit in his answer and also explain the PERL code a little.

Comment: @Asaph, added some suggestion about perl, thank you for nudge:)

Answer (score 4):

here's the issue: 1 && 5 returns 5 in perl.  you get the result you expect if you code the conditional as `if(($b=1) && ($a=5))`

Answer (score 2):

For Perl, fig. 2: `and` has a very low priority in perl, it's not a synonym of `&&`'s. Therefore the sample is executed as `(($a = 5) and ($b = 1))` which sets $a and $b to 5 and 1 respectively and returns a value of the last argument (i.e. 1).

After ++'s you get 6-2.

Answer (score 0):

refer to http://sillythingsthatmatter.in/PHP/operators.php for good examples